# BlackBerry ListField--How to open the selected list item

Tags: blackberry, java-me

how to open the selected list field in blackberry?

```
    listNames = new Vector();
    field = new ListField();

    ListCallBack _callback = new ListCallBack();
    field.setCallback(_callback);
    add(field);
    intialseList();
}

private void intialseList() {
    String name = "Sriaknth";
    String name2 = "pradeep";

    listNames.addElement(name);
    listNames.addElement(name2);
    reloadList();

}

private void reloadList() {
    field.setSize(listNames.size());
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

override navigationclick method in the screen , and on click, call `listNames.getSelectedIndex();`

Comment: it should be `field.getSelectedIndex()` instead of `listNames.getSelectedIndex();`

Answer (score 1):

you can override `navigationClick(int status, int time)` method in the class where you have added the ListField...

```
protected boolean navigationClick(int status, int time) {
    if(field.getSelectedIndex());
            return true;

}
```